# Does anybody know of a Windows Forms control for examining objects?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, controls

I have a WCF web service that returns many different lists of objects, formatted according to an XML Schema.

I have a simple winforms test rig for firing off the methods and I can use code breaks to examine the output using Quick Watch.

Does anybody know of a win forms control that can take an object and display useful information about it in the same way that Visual Studio can?

It would be really handy to drop on the form so I can examine the output of an installed service running on a remote site where I can't debug.

At the moment my only option is to write a huge win forms app customised to display the contents of each response individually.

My best idea at the moment is to serialize the response to XML and display it in a syntax colouring control called ScintillaNET.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called the [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx) control.

Comment: OMG Instant Awesome TestRig! 8D
Thanks!